# Isotope Combo Filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I used the [nice Tutorial](http://www.designlunatic.com/2011/08/isotope-tutorial/) for Isotope to create my Content.. Checked also on Isotope's site how to add a second Filtering but for as beginner it seems too hard.

I just want to add a second Navigation to filter by Month and Year.

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [this fiddle from the plugin author](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/wdSHh/) for *single* **and** *combination* filters; very little code is needed to make this work. You can tweak it there to find out how works.